# How to bind c structure with an array of another structure as a member, using pybind11?

Tags: c++, c, numpy, pybind11

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/pytypes.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <array>


    struct A{
        int a;
        float b[10];
    };

    struct B{
        int c;
        A d[5];
    };


    namespace py = pybind11;


    PYBIND11_MODULE(TestWrapper, m) {

        PYBIND11_DTYPE(A, a, b);

        py::class_<A>(m, "A")
            .def(py::init<>())
            .def_readwrite("a", &A::a)
            .def_property("b", [](A &p)->pybind11::array {
                auto dtype = pybind11::dtype(pybind11::format_descriptor<float>::format());
                return pybind11::array(dtype, { 10 }, { sizeof(float) }, p.b, nullptr);
                }, [](A& p) {});


        py::class_<B>(m, "B")
            .def(py::init<>())
            .def_readwrite("c", &B::c)
            .def_property("d", [](B &p)->py:array {
            auto dtype = pybind11::dtype(py::format_descriptor<A>::format(),1);
            return pybind11::array(dtype, { 10 }, { sizeof(A) }, p.d, nullptr);
            }, [](B& p) {});

        #ifdef VERSION_INFOB
        m.attr("__version__") = VERSION_INFO;
    #else
        m.attr("__version__") = "dev";
    #endif
    }
```

In the python Interface

```
import TestWrapper as tm

input = tm.A()
output = tm.B()
```

When I look at what is stored in output.d it says,

```
data type "^T{i:a:(10)f:b:}" not understood
```

I have also tried to make a this array using A in python like,

```
instancelist = [ tm.A() for i in range(29)]
output.d = instancelist
```

Bu this also resutled into some error. Any help to make the original code work or any sort of workaround will be appriciated.

Comment: Is there some reason for not using `std::array<A, 5>` instead of C-style array? If nope, then use it along with `#include "pybind11/stl.h"` and safe yourself the trouble.

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks for your comment. This works for this example. In the original task however, I am working on a project where I am not suppose to change the source code. Can you suggest something where I dont have to change the struct itself.

Comment: I am actually not sure if it is even possible, at least I didn't see any such use-case in pybind11 tests (which serves as "documentation" due to [terrible official docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#buffer-protocol)). If it is not allowed to touch the original code, I would just write a class wrappers for them. Do you need some example?

Comment: @pptaszni Even I am searching for the same but getting nothing. Even if I convert the c style array in the origianl code, how would I be able to use the functions which takes these structures as argument and as return type. Could you help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the valuable comment provided by @pptaszni. Here is what is my implemetation for the original problem.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/pytypes.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <array>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/complex.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h> 
#include <pybind11/chrono.h>

struct A{
    int a;
    float b[10];
};

struct B{
    int c;
    //std::array <A, 5> d;
    A d[5];
};

//function to be implemented with the original structure
bool doSomething(B* object)
{
    object->c = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            object->d[i].b[j] = 2;
        }
    return true;
}


//wrapper around the main function with the function wrapper
class MyclassB{

public:
    int c;
    std::array <A, 5> d;

    void doSomethingWrapper()
    {
        B b;

        doSomething(&b);

        c = b.c;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                d[i].b[j] = b.d[i].b[j];
            }

    }
};

namespace py = pybind11;


PYBIND11_MODULE(TestWrapper, m) {

    PYBIND11_NUMPY_DTYPE(A, a, b);

    py::class_<A>(m, "A")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("a", &A::a)
        .def_property("b", [](A &p)->pybind11::array {
            auto dtype = pybind11::dtype(pybind11::format_descriptor<float>::format());
            return pybind11::array(dtype, { 10 }, { sizeof(float) }, p.b, nullptr);
            }, [](A& p) {});

    py::class_<MyclassB>(m, "MyclassB")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("c", &MyclassB::c)
        .def_readwrite("d", &MyclassB::d)
        .def("doSomethingWrapper", &MyclassB::doSomethingWrapper);


    #ifdef VERSION_INFOB
    m.attr("__version__") = VERSION_INFO;
#else
    m.attr("__version__") = "dev";
#endif
}
```

On the python interface, code seems like the same

```
import TestWrapper as tm

input = tm.A()
output = tm.MyclassB()
output.doSomethingWrapper()
```

Comment: Hi Ankur, does this still work if the structures are defined in a header file? does  not work for me.

Comment: Hi @user3116936, i think it will work if you include the header file containing the defintation of the structure. Could you please post your sample code?

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify your structures just a bit, go for `std::array` because pybind11 has a support for STL containers, but not for raw arrays.

```
struct ModA{
  int a;
  std::array<float, 10> b;
};

struct ModB{
  int c;
  std::array<ModA, 5> d;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(xxx, m) {
  py::class_<ModA>(m, "ModA")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("a", &ModA::a)
    .def_readwrite("b", &ModA::b);
  py::class_<ModB>(m, "ModB")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("c", &ModB::c)
    .def_readwrite("d", &ModB::d);
}
```

This solution allows you to access fields `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in the read/write mode in python, however it is not possible to modify `std::array` single element, you need to modify a whole array at once.

If for some reason you absolutely must keep your structures intact, you might try to wrap them in C++ classes like this:

```
struct A{
  int a;
  float b[10];
};

class MyA
{
public:
  // + maybe some constructor accepting struct A
  int getInt() { return a_.a; }
  void setInt(int n) { a_.a = n; }
  std::array<float, 10> getArr() {
    std::array<float, 10> result;
    std::memcpy(result.data(), a_.b, 10*sizeof(float));
    return result;
  }
  void setArr(const std::array<float, 10>& arr) {
    std::memcpy(a_.b, arr.data(), 10*sizeof(float));
  }
  void setArrIdx(float val, size_t idx) { a_.b[idx] = val; }

private:
  A a_;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(xxx, m) {
  py::class_<MyA>(m, "MyA")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def("getInt", &MyA::getInt)
    .def("setInt", &MyA::setInt)
    .def("getArr", &MyA::getArr)
    .def("setArr", &MyA::setArr)
    .def("setArrIdx", &MyA::setArrIdx);
}
```

However, note that with `class MyB` it is getting more complicated, because you need to implement operations for converting your original `struct A` to your new `class MyA` every time you access the container of `class MyA` inside your `class MyB`. I would not go this way, unless absolutely necessary.

As for using your structs in pythonic functions, there is no problem, just use them like any other pythonic variable:

```
import xxx
var = xxx.ModB()
def foo(x):
  print(x.d)
  x.c = 69
  return x
var = foo(var)
print(var.c)
```

Comment: That's really helpful. I am going to extrapolate this methodolgy and going to write a wrapper on the functions accepting objects of B, so that I can internally change the Myclass to origianl structure before passing the argument. I will post the same here.